# Resurrection in node async function NodeJs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, sftp

I am trying to make a function to remote delete files over sftp with nodejs.

my function is like this

```
function dropdir(path){
                sftp.readdir(path, async(err, files)=>{
                    if(err)  console.log(err);//{ callback(err);  return err;}
                    
                    if(!files.length){
                    
                        await sftp.rmdir(path)
                    }else {
                        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            sfile= files[i];
                        
                            if(sfile.attrs.size == 4096){
                                await dropdir(path+"/"+ sfile.filename);   //recalling function with await
                                console.log(path);  //console.log of current working path
                            }else{
                                file_path= path+"/"+ sfile.filename;
                                await sftp.unlink(file_path)
                            
                            }
                        }
                        await sftp.rmdir(path)
                    }
                });
```

when i call the above function back in same with await it does not wait for self to complete.

in console.log i am getting

```
/home/ubuntu/hiiii
/home/ubuntu/hiiii/Links
/home/ubuntu/hiiii/Links/Links
/home/ubuntu/hiiii/Links/Links/Links
```

it means the dropdir was not waited for complete for last child

in simple this function is moving forward(parent to child) in directory direction insted of backword (child to parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the function as `async`.

Additionally, for `sftp.readdir` convert that callback style function into a `promisifed` function with [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

- await on `promisifedReadDir` assigning results to `const files`

and what code that was in the callback can now be on the same level and `await`ed on.